# Negation operators using quotes aren't honoured in search

Tags: bug, search

If you apply a `-` operator then it's not honoured by search if you're negating something that's quoted

For example, using `title`

```
is:question -title:"a b"
```

The search performed is actually:

> results found containing "a b" and not containing title: search options questions only

The same occurs when using `body`:

```
is:question -body:"a b"
```

searches for

> results found containing "a b" and not containing body: search options questions only

If I don't use any operator and negate a string then everything's fine

```
is:question -"a b"
```

searches for

> results found not containing "a b" search options questions only